# problems when sorting an array of integers using a quicksort algorithm

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, quicksort

I need to sort an array of ElemType elements (in this exercise ElemType is defined as integers of type int) (no, I can't use an array of int, because I need to use elemtype library).

this is my solution:

```
#include "vector.h"

void quicksort(Vector* v, ElemType* first, ElemType* last) {
    ElemType i, j, pivot; 
    if (*first < *last) {
        i = first; 
        j = last; 
        pivot = v->data[*last];
        do {
            while (v->data[i] < v->data[pivot]) i++; 
            while (v->data[j] > v->data[pivot]) j--; 
            if (i <= j) {
                ElemSwap(v->data[i], v->data[j]); 
                i++; j--; 
            }
        } while (i <= j); 
        quicksort(v, first, j); 
        quicksort(v, i, last); 
    }
}


void VectorSort(Vector* v) {
    if (v == NULL) {
        return; 
    }
    quicksort(v, 0, (size_t)((v->size))); 


}

int main(void) {
    Vector v = {.capacity = 4, .size = 2};
    Vector* ptr = &v; 
    ptr->data[0] = 4; ptr->data[1] = 1; 
    VectorSort(ptr); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I've implemented a quicksort algorithm.

I have used a ElemSwap and it's defined in ElemType.c (linked using ElemType.h, and vector.h)

in ElemType.c I have:

```
void ElemSwap(ElemType *e1, ElemType *e2) {
    ElemType tmp = *e1;
    *e1 = *e2;
    *e2 = tmp;
}
```

in vector.h I have:

```
#pragma once
#include "elemtype.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    ElemType* data;
} Vector;

void VectorSort(Vector* v);
```

when I debug vector.c I read: `"ptr->data was nullptr in line: "ptr->data[0] = 4; ptr->data[1] = 1;" (green squiggle)`

this is elemtype.c:

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include "elemtype.h"
    
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    void ElemSwap(ElemType *e1, ElemType *e2) {
        ElemType tmp = *e1;
        *e1 = *e2;
        *e2 = tmp;
    }
```

this is elemtype.h:

```
   #ifndef ELEMTYPE_INT_H_
    #define ELEMTYPE_INT_H_
    
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
   typedef int ElemType; 
void ElemSwap(ElemType *e1, ElemType *e2);

    
    
    
   
    #endif // ELEMTYPE_INT_H_
```

EDITED QUESTION: this is my updated solution

```
#include "vector.h"
void quicksort(Vector* v, size_t first, size_t last) {
    size_t i = 0; size_t j = 0; size_t pivot = 0; 
    if (first < last) {
        i = first; j = last; 
        pivot = v->data[last]; 
    }
    do {
        while (v->data[i] <= pivot) i++; 
        while (v->data[j] >= pivot) j--; 
        if (i <= j) {
            ElemSwap(&v->data[i], &v->data[j]); 
            i++; j--; 
        } 
    } while (i <= j); 
    quicksort(v, first, j);
    quicksort(v, i, last);
}
void VectorSort(Vector* v) {
    if (v == NULL) {
        return; 
    }
    quicksort(v, 0, v->size - 1); 
}


int main(void) {
    Vector* v = calloc(1, sizeof(Vector)); 
    if (v == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    v->size = v->capacity = 3;
    v->data = calloc(3, sizeof(v->data)); 
    if (v->data == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    v->data[0] = 2; v->data[1] = 1; v->data[2] = 7; 
    clock_t start; 
    clock_t end; 
    double cpu_time_used; 
    start = clock(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++) {
        VectorSort(v); 
    }
    end = clock(); 
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Sorted in t(s) %lf ", cpu_time_used / 11);

    return 0; 
}
```

it doesn't work, I don't have compile time errors/warnings, but I have this warning instead: "quicksort: recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow"

Comment: You are not initializing the `data` member of the vector `v`. It has nothing to do with the sorting algorithm.

Comment: OT: The variable `ptr` in your `main` function is not needed.

Comment: `quicksort(v, 0, (size_t)((v->size)));` invoked to a function expecting `void quicksort(Vector* v, ElemType* first, ElemType* last)` is a recipe for disaster *regardless* of what `ElemType` is , and frankly I'm shocked it compiles, much less does so without a raft of warnings. This is littered with similar inconsistencies and bugs.

Comment: I managed to [compile your code](https://godbolt.org/z/5MhGsc914) (assuming `ElemTyep` is `int`) and it produces a lot of warnings, all of which are actually errors.

Comment: @WhozCraig if you can, can you explain it better in an answer? I need to know

Comment: maybe the problem is located in *first and *last parameters

Comment: @Jabberwocky visual studio

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini no, the problem is your program compiles with warnings **which are actually errors** and there is no chance that this will work unless your program compiles without warnings.

Comment: ah okay sorry, now I got it, when I compile I've got 13 warnings

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini consider the warnings as errors.

Comment: This is turning into spoon-feeding. I'm stopping the discussion here. Maybe someone else will take over from here...