# read access violation while sorting an array of integers

Tags: arrays, c, quicksort

this question is related to my previous question (at this link: [problems when sorting an array of integers using a quicksort algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76170908/10101532)), I've edited my solution the following way:

```
#include "vector.h"

void QuickSort(Vector* v, size_t first, size_t last) {
    size_t i = 0; size_t j = 0;
    size_t pivot = 0;
    if (first <= last) {
        i = first; j = last; 
        pivot = (v->data[first] + v->data[last]) / 2; 
        do {
            while (v->data[i] < v->data[pivot]) i++;
            while (v->data[j] > v->data[pivot]) j--; 
            if (i <= j) {
                ElemSwap(&v->data[i], &v->data[j]); 
                i++; j--; 
            }
        } while (i <= j); 
        QuickSort(v, first, j); 
        QuickSort(v, i, last); 
    }
}
void VectorSort(Vector* v) {
    if (v == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    QuickSort(v, 0, v->size - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    ElemType v[16] = { 1, 3, 2, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    Vector* pv = calloc(1, sizeof(Vector)); 
    if (pv == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    pv->size = pv->capacity = 16; 
    pv->data = v; 
    VectorSort(pv); 
    return 0; 
}
```

recall, elemtype.c is defined this way:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "elemtype.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _unused(x) ((void)(x))

int ElemCompare(const ElemType *e1, const ElemType *e2) {
    return (*e1 > *e2) - (*e1 < *e2);
}

ElemType ElemCopy(const ElemType *e) {
    return *e;
}

void ElemSwap(ElemType *e1, ElemType *e2) {
    ElemType tmp = *e1;
    *e1 = *e2;
    *e2 = tmp;
}

void ElemDelete(ElemType *e) {
    _unused(e);
}

int ElemRead(FILE *f, ElemType *e) {
    return fscanf(f, "%d", e);
}

int ElemReadStdin(ElemType *e) {
    return ElemRead(stdin, e);
}

void ElemWrite(const ElemType *e, FILE *f) {
    fprintf(f, "%d", *e);
}

void ElemWriteStdout(const ElemType *e) {
    ElemWrite(e, stdout);
}
```

and elemtype.h is defined the following way:

```
#ifndef ELEMTYPE_INT_H_
#define ELEMTYPE_INT_H_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int ElemType;


int ElemCompare(const ElemType *e1, const ElemType *e2);


ElemType ElemCopy(const ElemType *e);


void ElemSwap(ElemType *e1, ElemType *e2);


void ElemDelete(ElemType *e);

int ElemRead(FILE *f, ElemType *e);


int ElemReadStdin(ElemType *e);


void ElemWrite(const ElemType *e, FILE *f);


void ElemWriteStdout(const ElemType *e);

#endif // ELEMTYPE_INT_H_
```

now, vector.h is:

```
#pragma once
#include "ElemType.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    ElemType* data;
} Vector;

void VectorSort(Vector* v);
```

this solution is better than the previous one, the problem is that when i debug i have a read access violation in these lines:

```
while (v->data[i] < v->data[pivot]) i++;
while (v->data[j] > v->data[pivot]) j--;
```

EDIT: as an user suggested in the comment section, I should've written:

```
while (v->data[i] < pivot) i++;
while (v->data[j] > pivot) j--;
```

because pivot is a number, and not an index

Comment: Is `pivot` an index in the array or a value in the array? You are using it like an index and setting it from the value.

Comment: it's an index but this is the formula to find the median

Comment: At some point `j` becomes negative and accessing `v->data[j]` then triggers the crash. Use the Visual Studio Debugger, it's very powerful yet easy to use.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've tried to use it but when I debug line-by-line program stopped and it points to these two lines so I can't use it, debugger is useful when program compiles but it doesn't compile so i can't see what the program does at each line

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini step through the code and monitor the variables. It works fine here. And make sure that `i` and `j` are always within valid bounds. As soon as one of these gets out of bounds you've done something wrong....

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini BTW. your program runs, therefore it compiles and therefore you can use the debugger, which is **very** useful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you meant `pivot = (first + last) / 2` ?

I'm not sure what it means to try to access `v->data[pivot]` when pivot is the floor of the mean between what's in start position and last position..

Comment: yes, but now I've edited the code this way: while (v->data[i] < pivot) i++;
while (v->data[j] > pivot) j--; because pivot is a number and not an index

Comment: Ok I think there is a bit of confusion on what's the mean, what's the median here. You should read the paragraph on QuickSort on Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot